# Swift application is not running on Ios 8 device

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swift, ios8, provisioning-profile

I created a swift based application which I can run on ios 8 simulator as well as device.When I made the .ipa file that won't run on ios device. I don't know that why the only .ipa is not able to run on device.

I can install the .ipa on an iOS 8 device but it exits as soon as I launch it.
I also created another sample application in swift that also won't run on ios 8 device.

Please help me out.

Comment: "But when i made the .ipa file that wont run on ios device" Did you obtain correct provisioning for this _.ipa_ file? (Presumably you would need an ad hoc deployment profile.)

Comment: Also, you say it exits. That means it crashes. Did you read the crash log? It can be very helpful.

Comment: Why not plug the device in and hit run then unplug, then you have a working version of the app on the device. Note that each device the app will run on must have its identifier included in your provision profile. If you want people to beta test your app, check out Testflight.

Comment: Hey i got it.I just remove revoked all certificates and removed all provisioning profile and again added new one.I don't how it worked but it worked.